# XSLT number of records after the grouping

Tags: xslt, count, grouping

I have a set of items which i am grouping using the muenchian method using keys. This is working great, my problem is, how to get the number of records after the grouping and use the number in the messages header?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl">
   <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
   <xsl:key name="groups" match="RECORD" use="VALUE"/>
   <xsl:template match="Test">
   <Header>
      <NoOfRecords>
         <HOW TO GET THE NO OF RECORDS= HERE?/>
      </NoOfRecords>
    </Header>
    <Message>
       <xsl:for-each select="RECORD[generate-id(.)=generate-id(key('groups',VALUE))]">
          <Value>
             <xsl:value-of select="VALUE/text()" />
          </Value>
       </xsl:for-each>
    </Message>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do it:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:key name="groups" match="RECORD" use="VALUE"/>
  <xsl:template match="Test">
    <xsl:variable name="distinctItems"
                  select="RECORD[generate-id()=generate-id(key('groups',VALUE)[1])]" />
    <Header>
      <NoOfRecords>
        <xsl:value-of select="count($distinctItems)"/>
      </NoOfRecords>
    </Header>
    <Message>
      <xsl:for-each select="$distinctItems">
        <Value>
          <xsl:value-of select="VALUE/text()" />
        </Value>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </Message>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Though I would of course recommend separating this into two templates:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:key name="groups" match="RECORD" use="VALUE"/>
  <xsl:template match="Test">
    <xsl:variable name="distinctItems"
                  select="RECORD[generate-id()=generate-id(key('groups',VALUE)[1])]" />
    <Header>
      <NoOfRecords>
        <xsl:value-of select="count($distinctItems)"/>
      </NoOfRecords>
    </Header>
    <Message>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="$distinctItems" />
    </Message>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="RECORD">
    <Value>
      <xsl:value-of select="VALUE/text()" />
    </Value>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```